# Laravel $request value is null

Tags: laravel

I want to make dropdown menu where you choose company and it shows you owners that are in that company but when i request data from my blade.php in my controller i get NULL. 
This is my blade.php

```
<form>
        <label>Company:</label>
        <select id="test" name="test" class="form-control input-sm"> 
            @foreach($companies as $company)
                <option value="{{$company->id}}">{{$company->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </form>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {       
        $companies = Company::all();
        $company_id = $request->get('company'); 
        $owners = Owner::where('company_id',$company_id)->get();  
    return view ('owners', compact('owners','companies'));
    }
```

and it's not showing any user but if I put any number manually like this

```
$company_id = 1;
```

then it shows owners from company where ID is 1.

**UPDATE 2**

My form looks like this now

```
<form action="{{ action('OwnerController@index') method="get"}}">
```

and my route is this

```
Route::get('owners', 'OwnerController@index');
```

Its still same.

Comment: where is your form action method ?

Comment: @AnarBayramov I don't have it, what should i put then?

Comment: can you print $request->all() above the return in the controller. and have you add any route for OwnerController@index ?

Comment: when i want to print that with echo I get this error `Array to string conversion`. No I didn't add  route for index method. I will make get route for index and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want. But here is something for you.

File => create.blade.php

```
<form action='/item' method='POST'>
    <label>Item Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-sm">

    <label>Company:</label>
    <select id="company" name="company" class="form-control input-sm"> 
        @foreach($companies as $company)
            <option value="{{ $company->id }}">{{ $company->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>
```

File => ItemController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'company_id' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|unique:items,name'
        ]);

        $obj = new Item();
        $obj->company_id = $request->input('company_id');
        $obj->name = $request->input('name');
        $obj->save();

        return redirect()->route('item.index')
            ->with('success', 'Create Successful');

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {

        Log::error($ex->getMessage());

        return redirect()->route('item.create')
            ->with('fail', $ex->getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: I want a dropdown menu where there are companies from my database and i want to use that dropdown in my Owner list so i can list owners from specific company.

Comment: this stores the company,he doesnt want that!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a form to fill your dropdown;
You create a relationship in your model between Company and Owner and you dont even need a where,simply use eloquent like this

```
$owners = Owner::get();
```

And then in your view simply get the company using eloquent:

```
$owner->company->name;
```

That's it done!

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: try method="get"

Comment: and for get that use $request->get('test'); 
if your problem still change Route::resource -> to -> Route::get

Comment: I did, just updated my question but still I have same problem.

Comment: change <form action="{{ action('OwnerController@index') method="get"}}">  -> to  -> <form action="/owners" method="get">

Comment: It's still same.

Comment: try **return $request->get('test');** on your function. and tell me the result.

Comment: Nothing just blank page.

Comment: If you created Request manually remove that. did you create that?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: request named 'Request' is premade request by laravel, if you create new one, remove that

Comment: I didn't make anything I just added `Request $request` to my index method and that's it.

Comment: It looks like I need some script so that will change.

Answer (score 0):

As I said before I was missing some script. This solved my problem.

```
<form method="get" id="company_change">
        <label for="company">Company:</label>
        <select id="company" name="company" onchange="document.getElementById('company_change').submit()"> 
        <option value="">----Select Company-----</option>
            @foreach($companies as $company)
                <option value="{{$company->id}}">{{$company->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </form>
```

My route is

```
Route::resource('owners', 'OwnerController');
```